# cmake can't find visual studio When using Ninja although it is installed and cygwin also installed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

i have  cygwin in path and visual studio also 
i like to build VS project for "Visual Studio 16 2019" host=x64 as this is what is installed .
i project is using Ninja and have to generate the project like this :

```
cmake -G "Ninja"  ..

CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/cygwin64/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Dev/my/a/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~1/2019/COMMUN~1/Common7/IDE/COMMON~1/MICROS~1/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_19d3d && ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: Access is denied.






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Your Cygwin is shadowing the Visual Studio compilers. Try to add ` -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=cl -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=cl` to your CMake call.

Comment: You could try running the command from the Visual Studio Developer Command prompt instead